# Cannot declare class in header file C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have little bit trouble with my code. I want to declare class in header file and call it to my CPP file. But i always get error, 'coba' is not a class or namespace name.

this is my header file, 'testFile.hpp' :

```
#pragma once

class coba
{
private:
    int num;
public:
    //coba();
    int getNum();
};
```

This is my CPP File, 'testFile.cpp' :

```
#include "testFile.hpp"
#include "pch.h"

int coba::getNum()
{
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: `pch.h` should come first.

Comment: Just remove `pch.h`.

Comment: Oow... Thank you for your help..StoryTeller

Comment: Removing it is the best solution if you don't know what it's for or how it works. When you understand C++ better, then you might want to consider it. It's not usually worth the trouble, though.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

### header file, 'testFile.hpp' :

```
#ifndef __coba__
#define __coba__

class Coba
{
private:
  int num;
public:
  Coba();
  int getNum();
};

#endif
```

### This is my CPP File, 'testFile.cpp' :

```
#include "testFile.hpp"

Coba::Coba()
{
}

int Coba::getNum()
{
  return 10;
}
```

Comment: Note that `__coba__` is an reserved identifier.

Comment: Prefer to provide annotations along with the code.  Let the readers know the differences between your code and the Poster's code.  Describe your solution.